# working with html form and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Im trying to make a simple post method using jquery. I know that a form in the html would read the user input in the form and pass it to a specific url. Here I have an input element placed outside the form, whenever submit button is clicked it is reading both the values declared inside the form and as well as outside the form. I want to read the values declared only inside the form element and ignore the value outside the form element, when a submit button is clicked. How to achieve it and what is the mistake I have made. (NOTE: The post URL given here is a dummy url)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="contactPage" id="contactPage" method="post" class="form-email">

            <h2> SIGN UP </h2>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First" required/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last" required />
            <br/> <br>
            <input type="tel" id="contactNum" placeholder="Phone Number" required/>
            <br/><br>
            <!-- <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required /> -->
            <br/><br>
            <input type="submit" class="postSubmit" value="Submit" required />
        </form>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#contactPage").submit(function(event){
      console.log("Button is Clicked");
      var userName = $('#firstName').val();
      var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
      var contactNum = $('#contactNum').val();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      var sendData = {"userId": contactNum,"key": email, "firstName": userName,"lastName": lastName};
     $.post({
              url: 'http://signup/backend',  //this url is not a working url 
              dataType: "json",
              data: sendData
            });
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: include onsubmit="return false;" to from tag like this <form name="contactPage" id="contactPage" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" class="form-email"> and try now

Comment: Still the value of email outside the form is read

Comment: i posted my sample workout as answer, try that :) hope it helps :) @ devanya

Answer (score 2):

the fastest way to collect the form data is using serialize method

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e){
$.post("MyUrl",this.serialize(),function(response){
alert(response);
})});
```

**UPDATE**

Be aware it will not work if the from enctype is **multipart-fromData**

if it is a multipart do something like this

```
  $("#myForm").submit(function (e){
 var fromData=new FromData(this)
$.post("MyUrl",fromData,function(response){
alert(response);
})});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your `sendData` variable as a JSON string.

```
$.post({
          url: 'http://signup/backend',  //this url is not a working url 
          dataType: "json",
          data: JSON.stringify(sendData)
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that  the problem here is that you are yourself reading the value of email field while sending the  whole data plus you are also including that variable in sendData object.
If you don't want to read the email data don't read that text value and also don't include that in your object.!!
Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.find()` to find input elements within form. This ensures that you get value of inputs that are within your form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#contactPage").submit(function(event){
        console.log("Button is Clicked");
        var userName = $("#contactPage").find('#firstName').val();
        var lastName = $("#contactPage").find('#lastName').val();
        var contactNum = $("#contactPage").find('#contactNum').val();
        var email = $("#contactPage").find('#email').val();
        var sendData = {"userId": contactNum,"key": email, "firstName": userName,"lastName": lastName};
        $.post({
              url: 'http://signup/backend',  //this url is not a working url 
              dataType: "json",
              data: sendData
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Got your problem. I think you are missing closing bracket for submit event.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hrgk0db/1/) Check value in console log.

Comment: Why? Any console error? It should work... I think you have commented Email field in your question. So you can't get email using .val().

Comment: To all the variable Im getting something like this r.fn.init[0]  . I don't see the value entered

Comment: You are missing closing bracket for submit event

Answer (score 0):

First create a html form

```
<form id="frm-report" >
       <input name="start_date" type="text" />
       <input name="end_date"  type="text" />
       <input name="selectionType" type="text" />
       <input name="optionsSelected"  type="text" />        
</form>
```

Second create a model with the parameters, names must be equals in form and class

```
namespace Test.Model.Models
{
    public class FormParams
    {
        public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
        public Int16 selectionType { get; set; }
        public string optionsSelected { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Third, create the ajax call using Jquery, and serialize the form in one var with the $("#frm-report").serializeArray();

```
var formData = $("#frm-report").serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: url_to_call,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data, jqXHR) {
                //ToDO when OK
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, errorThrown) {
                //ToDO when Error
            },
            complete: function () {
               //ToDO when Complete
            }
        });
```

The serialize only going to serialize "inputs", if you have a dropdown a need to send the value you have to do the following:

```
formData.push({ name: 'name_in_class', value: value_from_dropdown})
```

Fourth, create a method who will receive the form from ajax, the parameter type will be of the class type created

```
public JsonResult GenerateReport(FormParams param)
        {
  /// ToDO something with the values received
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to get the value of input field inside the form:

```
var email = $('#contactPage #email').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

my sample workout try this

Controller

```
public function workout()
    {



        if($this->input->post())
        {



            echo json_encode($this->input->post()); 

            exit();
        }

        $this->load->view('workout');
    }
```

view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="contactPage" onsubmit="return false;" id="contactPage" method="post" class="form-email">

            <h2> SIGN UP </h2>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First" required/>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last" required />
            <br/> <br>
            <input type="tel" id="contactNum" placeholder="Phone Number" required/>
            <br/><br>
            <!-- <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required /> -->
            <br/><br>
            <input type="submit" class="postSubmit" value="Submit" required />
        </form>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#contactPage").submit(function(event){
      console.log("Button is Clicked");



      var userName = $('#firstName').val();
      var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
      var contactNum = $('#contactNum').val();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      var sendData = {"userId": contactNum,"key": email, "firstName": userName,"lastName": lastName};
     $.post({
              url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/workout',  //this url is not a working url 
              dataType: "json",
              data: sendData,
              success: function (data)
              {
                console.log(data);
              }
            });



        });

     return false;

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my output in console is

```
Button is Clicked  
Object { userId: "9876543210", key: "user@stack.com", firstName: "user", lastName: "k" }
```